# Adding Features during Solution Update

Tags: deployment, upgrade, feature, solution-package

Is there a supported method to add features during a solution update.

We call `Update-SPSolution` and then upgrade our old features using `SPFeature.Upgrade`
but any new features in the solution do not appear to be deployed.

We could call `Install-SPFeature` for the missing features but we feel this is unsupported as `Get-Help Upgrade-SPSolution` displays the following

```
get-help Update-SPSolution

NAME
    Update-SPSolution

 SYNOPSIS
    Upgrades a deployed SharePoint solution.

DESCRIPTION
    The Update-SPSolution cmdlet upgrades a deployed SharePoint solution in the
    farm. Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same set of files
    and features as the deployed solution. If files and features are different,
    the solution must be retracted and redeployed by using the Uninstall-SPSolution
    and Install-SPSolution cmdlets, respectively.
```

This seems pretty clear cut and implies that solution update can only be used to deploy new versions Assemblies and existing files.

The same set of files comment does not make sense to use because of the existence of the [ApplyElementManifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595313.aspx) which only seems to be useful to apply new element manifests e.g. new webparts.

Have we misunderstood the use of ApplyElementManifest and MapFile?

What is the real world experience of adding Features during solution update?

Comment: Any other opinions?

Does any one have confidence in being able to deploy new Features during Update-Solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation states, when you add new artifacts to a solution you need to reinstall it. Really nothing new here, except for support for solution dependencies (and this is really only half implemented, since you can delete solutions that other solutions depend upon without getting any warning)

Feature upgrade is an entirely different matter. No upgrades are triggered when solutions are upgraded. As you state yourself you need to trigger the upgrade either through powershell or code.

Upgrading features has really received attention in SP2010. The new ways of upgrading features both declaratively and through code gives you really good ways of keeping your existing feature instances up to par with the feature definition.

In SP2007 feature manifests would only be fired once. ApplyElementManifests gives you the possibility to add new artifacts during upgrade.

MapFile gives you the possibility to point to new locations of files.

I recommend doing a search inside the FEATURE folder for real life examples, as the dev team used feature upgrade for both v2v (12 > 14) and b2b (beta > rtm) upgrades.

Also read my [whitepaper](http://andersrask.spoint.me/2010/03/22/whitepaper-on-sharepoint-upgrade/) on upgrade as it contains info on upgrading solutions and features and code in general.

I also wrote an article on feature upgrade for [DIWUG magazine](http://information-worker.org/freemagazine.aspx).

I can also recommend Chris O'Brien's [article series](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html) on feature upgrades.

Comment: I read the articles but they don't offer any advice on adding new Features during solution upgrade. What is your opinion?

Comment: The advice to check the Features Folder was excellent thank you. BasicWebPart/Feature.xml added new webparts during feature upgrade. So I guess we are safe to do the same too.

Comment: Its no problem adding new artifact thats what applymanifests are for, as long as u remember to use reactivation of solutions and not solution upgrade.

Comment: @AndersRask, good morning, Unfortunately the link to the whitepaper doesn't work. Could your correct it? thank you!